# how to split string into tokens outside main method

Tags: c++

I have seen this code on stack overflow,

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    vector<string> strings;
    istringstream f("denmark sweden india us");
    string s;    
    while (getline(f, s, ' ')) {
        cout << s << endl;
        strings.push_back(s);
    }
}
```

but I can't seem to understand why it is not working outside the main method. I have two files one has the main method and the other one I want to implement this code in it.

This is what I have tried

File1.h

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip> 
#include <string>

#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>

using pep::vector;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::string;
double evaluate(string str)
{

    vector<string> strings;
    istringstream f(str);
    string s;    
    while (getline(f, s, ' ')) 
{
    out << s << endl;
    strings.push_back(s);
}

    return 0;
}
```

File2.cpp

```
#include "file1.h"
int main() 
{
double answer = evaluate("3.0 4.0 +");
}
```

I got these errors:

```
file1.h: In function ‘double evaluate(std::__cxx11::string)’:
file1.h:89:5: error: ‘istringstream’ was not declared in this scope
     istringstream f(str);
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
file1.h:89:5: note: suggested alternative:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/6/ios:38:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/iostream:39,
                 from Stack.h:5:
/usr/include/c++/6/iosfwd:150:38: note:   ‘std::istringstream’
   typedef basic_istringstream<char>  istringstream;
                                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
file1.h:91:20: error: ‘f’ was not declared in this scope
     while (getline(f, s, ' '))
                    ^
file1.h:93:5: error: ‘out’ was not declared in this scope
     out << s << endl;
```

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Also describe *"is not working"* with as much detail as you can (error messages, expected/received output/ ...). That phrase on its own doesn't mean anything useful

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I edited it. Please let me know if anything else is needed. Thanks

Comment: @UnholySheep The thing is that it doesn't compile.

Comment: Compiler errors are usually *very* descriptive, telling you what is wrong (and I don't know why you didn't include the error in your question)

Comment: What is `pep::vector` and where does it come from?

Comment: @UnholySheep I added the errors. Thanks

Comment: @SamerTufail no, it is not a duplicate. I want to do it outside the main method which I tried to do it in the same way that is indicated in the answers of that question but it didn't work.

Comment: @UnholySheep I replaced it with 'std::vector' and it is still not compiling ( getting the same errors. )

Comment: `istringstream f(str);` -> `std::istringstream f(str);` (or put a `using std::istringstream` at the top like you did for the others) and `out` -> `cout`. Basically exactly what the errors are telling you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have many misspells in the code you provided. Please next time make sure your code is spellchecked before posted here.

Try changing the following lines to

```
using pep::vector; to  using std::vector;
istringstream f(str); to std::istringstream f(str);
out<<s<<endl; to  cout << s << endl;
```

changing that worked for me.

The first example u provided, you have

```
using namespace std;
```

so `istringstream f(str);` works without the scope operator.

Comment: Worked. Thanks for the answer